# How do I ensure parallel's Rscript.exe processes are closed with my R session?

Tags: r, windows, parallel-processing, cluster-computing, rscript

I am using the `parallel` package to run a server function multiple times at once. The server function loops until the session is manually stopped by the user.

It looks like:

```
library(parallel)

cluster <- makeCluster(3)
clusterCall(cluster, f)
```

On Windows, `parallel` works by creating an `Rscript` process for each worker in a cluster. However, these processes do not get closed when terminating the R session; they must be manually removed in the task manager. With a dozen or so workers, this is quickly becoming a hassle.

Is it possible to set these processes to close when the parent R session closes?

Comment: That doesn't work after you stop the session

Comment: I don't know what version of R you're using, but any recent version should automatically shut down the workers when you close the master.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You always must close the connections after the parallel processing. Try the following example:

```
library(parallel)

cluster <- makeCluster(3)
clusterCall(cluster, f)
stopCluster(cluster) # always add this line in the end of the script
```